# Find and replace in a array

Tags: loops

I have a array in which i need to do operations in some elements(i know the element numbers beforehand itslef) only, remaining elements can be left as such,

For Ex:
Input:

1,aaa,abcd,321

2,bbb,abcd,321

Operation -- Change the 2 & 3 elements length to 2

So expected output will be

1,aa,ab,321

2,bb,ab,321

Comment: Very clear. So where's your code?

Comment: `String[] IndPos = param1.split(",");
for(int i=0; i < (str_array.length - 1); i++)
{                        
for(int j=0; j<IndPos.length; j++)
{
if (i == ((Integer.parseInt(IndPos[j]) ) -1) )

{
sbf.append(str_array[i].substring(0,2)).append("|");
continue;
}                            
}                                                                   
sbf.append(str_array[i]).append("|");
}`

Comment: Put your code in the question, and add the language tag.